# Reusable TableViewCell loads an old image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a dynamic tableview that can be searched through with a search box, and if I load an image in a cell in the background and the search text changes, the object in the cell may also change, and sometimes an old image that was loading in the background will finish and display when it shouldn't.  Not every image is loaded in the same way, but this is the method that causes the problem:

```
    [self.CarImage sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL
                                 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageurl){
                                     [self.CarImage setAlpha:0.0];
                                     [UIImageView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
                                         [self.CarImage setAlpha:1.0];
                                     }];
                                 }];
```

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: In your completion block, ensure that you're being called from the main thread. (You can set a breakpoint to determine this). If you're being called from a background thread, you need to wrap your code inside a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()),...) to dispatch your UI code on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things here

1) in prepareforresue method Cancel current downloading request

2) in prepareforresue method set image to nil

Hope this will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is, image is loaded from url after you have already reused the cell. You can store the url of the image, each and everytime the cell being reused the url of the images should be stored inside the custom cell class. Then inside the completion block check that the loaded image url and the stored image url are same or not using [`isEqual:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl/1806686-isequal?language=objc) method of `NSURL`. If they are same then everything is ok, cell is not being reused, otherwise the cell is been used for another row, then just dont set the image.

```
self.carImgUrl = imageURL;//here carImgUrl is a property which you gonna set everytime when the cell is being reused.
[self.CarImage sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL
                             completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageurl){
                                 if([imageurl isEqual:self.carImgUrl])
                                 {
                                    [self.CarImage setAlpha:0.0];
                                     [UIImageView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
                                         [self.CarImage setAlpha:1.0];
                                     }];
                                 }
                             }];
```